# SBCL REPL Wrong Reuse of Cons Cells?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

What's going on in the interaction with SBCL REPL below (the last form)?

```lisp
TEST> (acons 'k 'v1 nil)
((K . V1))
TEST> (assoc 'k *)
(K . V1)
TEST> (push 'v2 (cdr *))
(V2 . V1)
TEST> (cdr '(K . V1))
(V2 . V1)
```

This is a bug, I guess?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in sbcl 2.3.8. I get `V1` as expected.

Comment: Maybe this behavior falls under the category of the mistake of updating literal data, resulting in undefined behavior?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but you don't have any literal lists that you're modifying.

Comment: I also tried to reproduce it by replacing the first line with the literal `'((k . v1))`, but it didn't reproduce.

Comment: Thanks @Barman. I'm using version 2.1.11. It's good to know that it's fixed.

Comment: The actual behavior (of SLIME) is clarified in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible interaction problem might be caused by using *presentations* in SLIME.

I'm using SLIME and SBCL.

```
CL-USER> (acons 'k 'v1 nil)
((K . V1))
CL-USER> (assoc 'k *)
(K . V1)
CL-USER> (push 'v2 (cdr *))
(V2 . V1)
CL-USER> (cdr '(K . V1))
(V2 . V1)
CL-USER>
```

So, I can get the same result as you. Strange, isn't it? But there might be an explanation for it. What did I do?

**First**: SLIME can use *presentations* and not just textual data. A *presentation* is a textual representation of the actual data. The text then is still linked to the underlying data.

I'm typing: `(acons 'k 'v1 nil)`

```
CL-USER> (acons 'k 'v1 nil)
```

SLIME *presents* the result list:

```
((K . V1))
```

I'm typing: `(assoc 'k *)`

```
CL-USER> (assoc 'k *)
```

SLIME *presents* the result list:

```
(K . V1)
```

I'm typing: `(push 'v2 (cdr *))`

```
CL-USER> (push 'v2 (cdr *))
```

SLIME *presents* the result list:

```
(V2 . V1)
```

Now it gets interesting. I'm typing `(cdr '` and then I'm copying the *presentation* `(K . V1)` from above by copy/paste. I'm not typing the list, I'm copying it. Then I type `)`.

```
CL-USER> (cdr '(K . V1))
```

The underlying data of the *presentation* has changed. SLIME tells SBCL to evaluate `(cdr '(K V2 . V1))`. SLIME uses the value of the presentation, not it's actually displayed characters.

Thus the result is:

```
(V2 . V1)
```

Next, we can see the actual changed *presentation*'s value: I'm writing a quote character first, then I again copy the `(K . V1)` *presentation* from above.

```
CL-USER> '(K . V1)
(K V2 . V1)
```

The result above shows that *what you see is **not** what you get*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Now it's clear. Also the text copied from previous outputs gets different color, proving that Slime distinguishes them from text typed directly.

Comment: I don't have this problem with SLY. What's the point of this "presentation value" of slime?

Comment: @JérômeRadix It allows you to use copy-paste to refer to higher-level objects